# Microsoft updates feed

Tags: web, patch-management

I'm trying to write a web scraper that will pull together information about security updates for various products but I cannot find one for microsoft products.

As this is cross-platform and includes 3rd party programs too, a WSUS isn't going to do the job for me. Has anyone else tried to implement anything similar and found somewhere they can pull the information from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a series of feeds from Microsoft that come from the Microsoft Security Techcenter [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/security/bb291012).  The two main ones I get alerts from are security bulletins and security advisories.